# php & mysql syntax errors: possibly string?

Tags: php, string

Having a problem with some code and string handling

> Syntax error, unexpected end of file...

Can someone help?

```
<?php

    require("common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {

        header("Location: login.php");

        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }

    $query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            email,
            gold
        FROM users
    ";

    try
    {

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }


    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10
WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."');

header('Location: quests.php');
die();

?>
```

Comment: You forget to add " and the end of the query mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10 WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the quoted string:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10
WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10 WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."');
```

You have forgotten to close the quote `"`

Should be like this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10 WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `"` on your `mysqli_query` line:

```
."');
```

needs to be

```
."'");
```

If your editor doesn't make this very obvious with syntax hilighting, you should use a different editor.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that and now have returned two more errors... mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null and Cannot modify header information - headers already sent on line 38 which says **bold**WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");**bold** and thank you for the format changes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10
WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."');
```

use

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET gold = gold + 10
WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");
```